# Highstock: When legend under the chart has many items, the chart height is small. How can I fix the height?

Tags: charts, highcharts, series

In my app users can add/remove as many series they want to the HighStock component using a piece of UI I wrote. However, when a user adds multiple time-series and the legend is under the chart, it shrinks the chart's height (in favor of the legend). This way the overall height remains constant.

However, I'm interested in having the plotting area keeping the same height and still have the legend be under it, changing the *overall* height if needed.

`code`
Here's a [fiddle to demo the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/9vZ8F/).

Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set maxHeight property. this will fix the maximum height of legend and gives navigation to legend.

```
maxHeight: 100,
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9vZ8F/2/

instead if you remove

```
layout:'vertical'
```

legend will not occupy much space
here is a fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/9vZ8F/1/

Hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely progress and puts me in a better situation then before. Any way to fix the plotting area height?

Comment: You can't set fixed height for plotting area. You can try to set yAxis.height.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing a calculation on the number of series you have and adjusting the chart height based on that?

```
var series = [{
        name: 'series 1',
        data: usdeur
    }, {
        name: 'series 2',
        data: usdeur
    }, {
        name: 'series 3',
        data: usdeur
    }, {
        name: 'series 4',
        data: usdeur
    }, {
        name: 'series 5',
        data: usdeur
    }    
    ],
        height = 400 + (series.length * 15);

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {
            borderWidth: 2,
            height: height
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },
        navigator: {
            //top: 200
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: series
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SSn4e/